# How to access videos or binary files outside the public_html or www directory?

Tags: php, html

I have built a php application which uploads the video files in a directory outside the **PUBLIC_HTML** or **www** directory. The application works locally I can access the HTML5 videos outside the **PUBLIC_HTML** or **www** directory like this:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="../movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

I want only registered users to access these files but since folders is public can everybody access the videos simply by typing the URL?
If I host this app, will these video files still be viewable? 
If I have to put the uploading directory inside the **PUBLIC_HTML** or **www** directory and upload files in there, what is the best way to restrict public access to the video links.
I also have blank index.html file in that folder to prevent public from viewing the files in that directory.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You want public access by allowing them to be viewed, but you don't want public access? If you can access them with a `<source>` tag, then you can access them with a direct link.

Comment: If the are not publicly available then you need to serve the content of the files with PHP directly.

Comment: @prodigitalson Ok I want registered users to access videos in a web page but I don't want everybody to access the videos simply by typing the video url. What is the best option in your opinion?

Comment: I don't want public to access but registered users. However, everybody can access those videos or files.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you can have a look to .htaccss file and to configure to manage permissions for your directory.

http://www.sitepoint.com/htaccess-for-all/

Hope that helps,
·_-